# Creating new property in Record<string, string> says that new value can be undefined

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings

I upgraded to typescript 4-beta and my reducers where my state is typed with Record<string, string> are showing my that when I create new property with value in them, then the value can be undefined.
I dont know if I really understand what is going on or is this some sort of bug.
On version 3.9 it this kind of error did not show up.

```
Type '{ [x: string]: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'. Index signatures are incompatible. Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Here is TS playground with example.

```
type State = Record<string, string>

const initialState = {};

const reducer = (state: State = initialState, action: {type: string; payload: {key: string, value: string}}):State => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "foo":
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.payload.key]: action.payload.value
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oCUIGMD2AnAJgDwDOwuAlgHYDmANFKRTQHwBQrOlpUV5w58ADZxEKKAG8AvgG52nbrgj4Arpgi4oqABSlRALlgIkmnpT4DhRiPXiZ+2SgfGhIBxlWrSoYeCEHZ4fCcAawgQNzIPegA3IWUICKZqSUkASj0RY2RmCVYofIYAdz5MAAstW3tKADoXCFTcgqaoTHhiaAAiADNsbA69POahxWBlXEpGoan86tndJFpB6aGAbUryB2qfPwD8atCQAF0Ddc3t-0Dq2MF4peXJO6b8CC74ZUFgAeWCkbGJ+YgsiaD0kQA)

Many thanks maybe I am just dumb and I am doing somthing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue ([microsoft/TypeScript#39494](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39494)) and is already fixed in the current nightly builds of TypeScript 4.0 (see [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-dev.20200725#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oCUIGMD2AnAJgDwDOwuAlgHYDmANFKRTQHwBQrOlpUV5w58ADZxEKKAG8AvgG52nbrgj4Arpgi4oqABSsoehgiQAuWIbG9+QkUlq798TP2yUT4qKEgnGVatKhh4EEFseHxXKABrCBAvMh96ADchZQhYpmooSUzWAEoTaxRmCTs9YgB3PkwACygtBydKADoPCBzi-Q6oTHhiaAAiADNsbD6jEs6OxWBlXEp2iYW9RuXSUVtFxYBtevJnRoCgkPxGqJAAXRMdvYPg0MakwRTxxcln-XwIAfhlQWAxjf0Uxmc1WSFkHVer1YQA)).  So when TS 4.0 is officially released this is probably not going to be an issue.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I could not find this issue.